# Obtain mean of values computed through foreach

Tags: r, foreach

Suppose you have a bunch of computations, which you want to execute using [`foreach`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/index.html). Perhaps you want to parallelize them, now or in the future. Each computation returns a single number. What is the best idiom to obtain the mean of all the numbers computed in this fashion?

I have two solutions in mind, which I'll post as possible answers so that you can vote and comment on these individually, and perhaps even edit them to improve them. But I guess there might be even better ways, so additional answers are welcome. My answers will include examples which you can adopt to demonstrate your own techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution accumulates the results in a vector, and eventually executes the `mean` function on that.

```
> foreach(i = icount(300), .combine = c, .inorder = FALSE, .multicombine = TRUE,
+         .final = mean) %do% { i*7 %% 11 }
[1] 1053.5
```

Benefits:

- Works with nested `foreach` calls as well
- Works with aggregating functions other than `mean` as well
- Does not require any knowledge about the number of values in the iteration

Drawbacks:

- Collects all the results into a vector first, which might consume unneccessary amounts of memory, particularly when performing a huge number of very small jobs.

Comment: This isn't directly related to your primary Q and A, sorry. How will parallel code behave on a huge number of small jobs? I would suspect a lot of overhead would be involved, seriously curbing the advantages of parallel computing.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, I'm not sure about whether this really works with all backends, but in theory foreach should make an attempt to bunch jobs together in such a way that each worker executes a number of them before returning anything. If that works, a huge number of small jobs with single number result might work like a smaller number of larger jobs with multi-number results. But foreach itself makes no guarantees about this.

Answer (score 0):

One solution accumulates the results into a single sum, and eventually divides this sum by the number of iterations.

```
> foreach(i = icount(300), .combine = '+', .inorder = FALSE,
+         .final = function(x) x/300) %do% { i*7 %% 11 }
[1] 1053.5
```

Benefits:

- Only requires memory for a single numeric sum, which should be a performance gain
- Works with nested `foreach` calls as well

Drawbacks:

- The number of iterations has to be repeated in the argument list of `foreach`. In this example, the number was a constant so this was easy, and using a single variable or even the length of a single vector shouldn't be much harder. But in cases where the iteration spans multiple vectors, or iterators of unknown size, things might become more difficult and errors due to inconsistent modifications might go unnoticed.